# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when trying to connect to Raspberry

Tags: javascript, json, browser, xmlhttprequest, raspberry-pi

I'm working with my Raspberry Pi.
I have my raspberry Pi, that on the IP: 192.168.X.X/file.json  give me a webpage containing data in json. While trying to built a web page that requests in that page with the following code:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.X.x:8080/file.json', function(data) {
    //code  }
```

It returns the an error on the browser:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.X.X:8080/file.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Can you tell me how to fix it? 
And where to put the code to fix it?

Comment: This is a CORS issue : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS You have to add the following headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *` to your server's response (`*` is for dev purpose, you should put the requesting domain in production). What server techology are you using ?

Comment: The browser doesn't want the current webpage to talk to other webpages. You wouldn't get this error if you ran that JavaScript while your browser was already on a page hosted by your Raspberry Pi. You can either design the page to allow it to be accessed from other webpages (CORS, as mentioned above) or you can host that JavaScript on an html page on the Raspberry Pi, which will also get you around this issue while you're developing your JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to [`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS): basically, you cannot access a domain via Ajax if it's not allowed on the server side. This is a "security" feature on most modern browsers. You won't encounter this problem using command line such as curl or chrome's Postman extension.

Make sure the domain requesting the data (`localhost`) is allowed in the Access-`Control-Allow-Origin` header, as well as the http verb (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`... or `*` for every http methods).

Basically, it comes down to add the two following headers to the `http://192.168.X.x/` server's response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

If you use `node.js` with `Express`, you can do the following :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  // or res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your web server to set the appropriate CORS response headers.